# Hiding Object in Bootstrap Layout Without Shifting Other Elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide #bubble-three and #bubble-two without shifting the position of #bubble-one or the image. I have tried applying visibility: hidden to these two objects, but it seems like this causes the first two rows to shrink, thus pushing #bubble-one and the image to the top of the screen. Is there any way to keep the bootstrap grid and avoid resorting to absolute positioning? Below is my HTML.

HTML:

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "text-center">
        <h1 id="bubble-three">Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
    <div>
        <p id="bubble-two">Some Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-xs-9">
        <p id="bubble-one"></p>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-3">
        <img src = "http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" id = "filler">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can set there opacity to 0

so

```
 #bubble-three,
 #bubble-two{
     opacity: 0;
 }
```

this will basically turn these elements invisible without shifting the layout, so they are basically still there.. they are just invisible

Comment: Dont forget to mark my answer as correct if it helped you, thanks!